# How can I access multidimentional associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I have this array return from a database query. I'm not sure how can I retrieve the value for [url]?

Please advice. Thanks.

```
Array (
[1] => Array (
[0] => Array (
[url] => ''
[poster] => ''
[skin] => siteorigin
[ratio] => 1.777
[autoplay] => 0
[info] => Array (
[grid] => 0
[cell] => 0
[id] => 0
[class] => ''
)
)
[1] => Array (
[title] =>
[text] => ''
[filter] => 1
[info] => Array (
[grid] => 1
[cell] => 0
[id] => 1
[class] => WP_Widget_Text
)
)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine if you're legitimately just trying to get the value from that particular array:

```
$arr[1][0]['url']
```

Multidimensional arrays are just arrays within arrays, so each bracket operator yields a new array which can be additional dereferenced until you get the value you want.